# How to understand the Swap event payload?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, pancakeswap

I am trying to wrap my head around [pancakeswap](/questions/tagged/pancakeswap) `Swap` event (which should be equivalent to [uniswap](/questions/tagged/uniswap)).

Here is an example transaction: [`0xd809e359a4037eb5e2617769b93f8b7fa1e708c37019b02933e1845e33c99884`](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xd809e359a4037eb5e2617769b93f8b7fa1e708c37019b02933e1845e33c99884)

This transaction contains `Swap` event:

```
Swap (
  index_topic_1 address sender,
  uint256 amount0In,
  uint256 amount1In,
  uint256 amount0Out,
  uint256 amount1Out,
  index_topic_2 address to
)
```

and it has the following values:

```
sender: 0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e
amount0In: 12772329830235
amount1In: 2562091000000000000
amount0Out: 208940457743532637
amount1Out: 0
to: 0x97c2727b8f0584f45f86d2d3dead77e5c74814bc
```

and this event originates from contract [`0xff3dd404afba451328de089424c74685bf0a43c9`](https://bscscan.com/address/0xff3dd404afba451328de089424c74685bf0a43c9).

As far as I understand,

- `amount0` relates to `token0` as defined in [`0xff3dd404afba451328de089424c74685bf0a43c9`](https://bscscan.com/address/0xff3dd404afba451328de089424c74685bf0a43c9)
- `amount1` relates to `token1` as defined in [`0xff3dd404afba451328de089424c74685bf0a43c9`](https://bscscan.com/address/0xff3dd404afba451328de089424c74685bf0a43c9)

In this case,

- `token0` is [SafeMoon](https://bscscan.com/address/0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3) contract (9 decimals)
- `token1` is [Wrapped BNB](https://bscscan.com/address/0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c) (18 decimals)

If I am reading this event correctly, it says that we are trading WBNB 0.2562091 for SafeMoon 208,940,457.

However,

- BscScan [shows](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xd809e359a4037eb5e2617769b93f8b7fa1e708c37019b02933e1845e33c99884) that the actual amount transferred is 188,046,411. This can also be seen by looking at the logs, `Transfer` event.
- It is not clear what role does `amount0In` (`12772329830235`) play in `Swap` event.

How does one determine by looking at the `Swap` event that we traded WBNB 0.2562091 for SafeMoon 208,940,457?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use this transaction as an example:

https://bscscan.com/tx/0xf30f0de71911e52c68a6e4b5e3821eed3fe00e0c51b2650a028c82afdcc862b0#eventlog

As a benchmark, let's use BoggedFinance data. It says that:

```
bnb_usd=342
phx_usd=0.00000000570810
bnb_phx=60643119461
```

```
PHX - BNB LP PancakeSwap V2
7,924,800,360.499 PHX + 0.131 BNB
Liquidity Pool Totals
Pool adds $631,122 to total liquidity
PHX pooled: 55,236,876,104,150
BNB pooled: 910
Total LP Tokens: 6,970
KI pooled: 1,314,655,947,122
BNB pooled: 0.000
Total LP Tokens: 2,141.465
```

It is a swap between these two tokens:

```
Token0: PHX
Token0.decimals=9
Token0.address: 0xb98d864ddcb573567b3a2258c9e5cab58fe7974e
```

```
Token1: WBNB
Token1.decimals=18
Token1.address: 0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c
```

Other addresses mentioned in the logs:

```
Initiator: 0xC5f0Ac8AEd9D12C0645d16aB5892bb09Fc297590
Router (v2): 0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e
PHX-WBNB LP: 0x2c3a0aa216cefb8c887716b993c3158f011f967e
```

BscScan says that the following amounts were transferred:

```
For 0.1 ($34.01) Wrapped BNB (WBNB)
For 5,314,263,769 PhoenixProtocol (PHX)
```

i.e. 0.1 WBNB was transferred in exchange for 5,314,263,769 PHX

```
actual=5,314,263,769 = 5,314,263,769
```

However, if we were to use Bogged provided quote, the expected amount should be:

```
0.1 x bnb_phx = 6,064,311,946.1

expected=6,064,311,946

((expected-actual)/((expected+actual)/2))*100 = 13.18351603551288580585
```

i.e. We would expect 13.18% more than what we got.

0.2% is a PancakeSwap fee.

The rest must be a combination of slippage and error between when the Bogged values were observed and when the trade took time (it is volatile market afterall).

A comment in the contract states that there is a 10% fee on every transaction, which may account for the difference.

The following events have been recorded:

```
Deposit
Address: 0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c
Destination: 0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e
Wad: 100000000000000000
```

This is initiator transferring 0.1 (100000000000000000/10^18) WBNB to Router.

```
Transfer
Address: 0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c
Source: 0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e
Destination: 0x2c3a0aa216cefb8c887716b993c3158f011f967e
Wad: 100000000000000000
```

This is Router adding 0.1 WBNB to PHX-WBNB LP.

```
Transfer
Address: 0xb98d864ddcb573567b3a2258c9e5cab58fe7974e
Source: 0x2c3a0aa216cefb8c887716b993c3158f011f967e
Destination: 0xc5f0ac8aed9d12c0645d16ab5892bb09fc297590
Wad: 5314263769851279617
```

This is PHX-WBNB LP sending 5,314,263,769 (5314263769851279617/10^9) to Buyer.

```
Sync:
Address: 0x2c3a0aa216cefb8c887716b993c3158f011f967e
Reserve0: 54569750545915728248786
Reserve1: 921958306311444356872
```

This event indicates that PHX-WBNB LP have been updated.

```
Swap
Address: 0x2c3a0aa216cefb8c887716b993c3158f011f967e
Sender: 0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e
Addressee: 0xc5f0ac8aed9d12c0645d16ab5892bb09fc297590
amount0In: 12888802144710313
amount1In: 100000000000000000
amount0Out: 5904737522056977352
amount1Out: 0
```

This event describes how much was sold (`amount0In`, `amount1In`) and how much was received (`amount0Out`, `amount1Out`).

What's interesting is that 5904737522056977352 does not align with the actual amount transferred.

```
amount_out=5,904,737,522
actual=5,314,263,769
```

i.e. actual amount is 10.52% less than what `amount_out` says

```
((actual-amount_out)/((actual+amount_out)/2))*100 = -10.52631580448580946687
```

There is also the `amount_in_0` parameter.

```
amount_in_0=12,888,802
```

This equal to 0.2% of the amount_out, which appears to be PancakeSwap fee.

```
(amount_in_0/amount_out)*100 = 0.21827899973501988968
```

At the end, `amount_out` does not account for 10%, which aligns with the advertised contract fee, and it seems that there is no way to get the actual amount transferred just by looking at the `Swap` event.

It is worth noting that the quote that we calculated using two reserves does not reflect the 10% fee, i.e. The initial expected amount (6,064,311,946) closely aligns with the `amount0Out` (5,904,737,522).

i.e. Looks like the only way to get the actual amount is by looking at the `Transfer` events.

Answer (score 1):

PancakePair [_swap](https://bscscan.com/address/0xff3dd404afba451328de089424c74685bf0a43c9#code) function:

```
    // this low-level function should be called from a contract which performs important safety checks
function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external lock {
    require(amount0Out > 0 || amount1Out > 0, 'Pancake: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT');
    (uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1,) = getReserves(); // gas savings
    require(amount0Out < _reserve0 && amount1Out < _reserve1, 'Pancake: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');

    uint balance0;
    uint balance1;
    { // scope for _token{0,1}, avoids stack too deep errors
    address _token0 = token0;
    address _token1 = token1;
    require(to != _token0 && to != _token1, 'Pancake: INVALID_TO');
    if (amount0Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token0, to, amount0Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
    if (amount1Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token1, to, amount1Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
    if (data.length > 0) IPancakeCallee(to).pancakeCall(msg.sender, amount0Out, amount1Out, data);
    balance0 = IERC20(_token0).balanceOf(address(this));
    balance1 = IERC20(_token1).balanceOf(address(this));
    }
    uint amount0In = balance0 > _reserve0 - amount0Out ? balance0 - (_reserve0 - amount0Out) : 0;
    uint amount1In = balance1 > _reserve1 - amount1Out ? balance1 - (_reserve1 - amount1Out) : 0;
    require(amount0In > 0 || amount1In > 0, 'Pancake: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT');
    { // scope for reserve{0,1}Adjusted, avoids stack too deep errors
    uint balance0Adjusted = (balance0.mul(10000).sub(amount0In.mul(25)));
    uint balance1Adjusted = (balance1.mul(10000).sub(amount1In.mul(25)));
    require(balance0Adjusted.mul(balance1Adjusted) >= uint(_reserve0).mul(_reserve1).mul(10000**2), 'Pancake: K');
    }

    _update(balance0, balance1, _reserve0, _reserve1);
    emit Swap(msg.sender, amount0In, amount1In, amount0Out, amount1Out, to);
}
```

Safemoon [whitepaper](https://safemoon.net/whitepaper):

> Safemoon Protocol SafeMoon employs 3 simple functions: Reflection + LP
> acquisition + Burn In each trade, the transaction is taxed a 10% fee,
> which is split 2 ways.
>
> - 5% fee = redistributed to all existing holders
> - 5% fee is split 50/50 half of which is sold by the contract into BNB,
>   while the other half of the SAFEMOON tokens are paired automatically
>   with the previously mentioned BNB and added as a liquidity pair on
>   Pancake Swap.

Amount0Out `208940457743532637` is calculated outside `_swap` function and sent to `_safeTransfer` function as a parameter:

```
if (amount0Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token0, to, amount0Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
```

Safemoon contract actually transfers to recipient specified amount of tokens minus 10% (5% tax fee and 5% liquidity fee)
`208940457743532637 - 10% = 188046411969179375` and emits Transfer event.
Then, PancakePair _swap function emits Swap event with base value of Amount0Out `208940457743532637`

---

Amount0In is greater than zero because Safemoon contract returns part of safemoon tokens as a liquidity pair on Pancake Swap.

```
uint amount0In = balance0 > _reserve0 - amount0Out ? balance0 - (_reserve0 - amount0Out) : 0;
```