# Why does swap event have amount0in, amount1in, amount0out, amount1out?

Tags: etherscan, uniswap, events

Why not simply just amountIn and amountOut? Why have 4 properties?

```
event Swap(
  address indexed sender,
  uint amount0In,
  uint amount1In,
  uint amount0Out,
  uint amount1Out,
  address indexed to
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`amount0In`, `amount1In` describe how much was sold, and `amount0Out`, `amount1Out` describe how much was received in the token swap.

See: [How to understand the Swap event payload?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99553/how-to-understand-the-swap-event-payload)